# Dockerfile CMD not running, but the command works when use inside the container

Tags: python-2.7, dockerfile

I want to run a python web app in a container, but the CMD in dockerfile isn't running (`CMD ["gunicorn","--config","python:config","web:app"]`). When I use the command, `"gunicorn --config python:cpnfig web:app"`, in the container, it works (in this condition, the container starts with `"/bin/bash"`).
How can I modify the CMD in dockerfile to run the app?

Comment: can you share your `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: FROM python:2.7 EXPOSE 9090
RUN pip install bottle requests beaker oss2 gevent gunicorn \
    && git clone xxxxxxxxx
ENV PYTHONPATH /log
WORKDIR /log
CMD ["gunicorn","--config","python:config","web:app"]

Comment: What was the response while you run the docker? I mean this command, `docker run your_image_name` ?

Comment: no response, the container started and then exited

Comment: Did you get this sorted? I have the same issue.